# sample apks for certificate pinning bypass practice

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, frida

I'm working on android security and I was trying to use frida-tools to bypass ssl pinning on android.
I completely know how to work with this framework, but i wasn't able to find any sample apks for practicing. is there any sample apk for this purpose available?!

thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you have already apps installed that use pinning: Google Play Store respectively Play Services.

Comment: @Robert frida ssl unpinnning script doesn't work on all apps, so i am looking for a sample app which works with this framework. i need it for academic purposes.

Comment: If it is for academic purposes I would search GitHub of sample pinning apps (that don't use OkHttp3). E.g. this one: https://github.com/nelenkov/cert-pinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia) app for android is [open source](https://codeshare.frida.re/@masbog/frida-android-unpinning-ssl/) and has 2 different certificate pinning implementations.

[Solutions](https://codeshare.frida.re/@masbog/frida-android-unpinning-ssl/) @ lines 41 & 96